Insights on using the HypergeometricDistribution functions in Mathematica
I'm trying to calculate the upper confidence interval for the hypergeometric distribution in mathematica and I came up with this very simple code.
UpperBoundHypergeometric[N_, n_, x_, p_] := 
 Module[{k, cumulativeProb},
  k = Ceiling[N x/n];
  While[k <= N && CDF[HypergeometricDistribution[n, k, N], x] > p, k++];
  Min[k, N]]

UpperBoundHypergeometric[10000, 200, 100, 
  10^-15] // AbsoluteTiming

{1.75479, 7592}

The code starts with k=Ceiling[N x/n] and increments by 1 while evaluating the CDF.
I need to call this function multiple times and I need to squeeze out as much performance out of Mathematica.
Are there other function related to probability distributions that are better performing, which can be used instead?
EDIT
I made some improvements, especially for very large input values.

upper = Compile[{{method, _Real, 0}, {beta, _Real, 0}, {x, _Real, 
     0}, {n, _Real, 0}},
   Module[{k, xcp},
    k = (2/(9 n)) beta ;
    xcp = (1 - 2 k)/(1 + k);
    If[n == 0., 0, 
     If[x >= n, n, 
      If[x <= n xcp, 
       n (1/(1 + 4 k)) (3 k + (1 - 2 k) x/n + 
          3 Sqrt[k (k + x/n - (x/n)^2)]), 
       n (((1 - (4 beta)/(9 n))^2/(1 + (2 beta)/(9 n)) + 
           Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(
            beta (-((1 - (4 beta)/(9 n))^2/(1 + (2 beta)/(9 n))^2) + (
               1 - (4 beta)/(9 n))/(1 + (2 beta)/(9 n)) + (2 beta)/(
               9 n)))/n] + (2 beta)/(3 n))/(
          1 + (8 beta)/(
           9 n)) + ((1 - (4 beta)/(9 n) + (
             beta (1 - (2 (1 - (4 beta)/(9 n)))/(
                1 + (2 beta)/(9 n))))/(
             Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(
              beta (-((1 - (4 beta)/(9 n))^2/(1 + (2 beta)/(
                    9 n))^2) + (1 - (4 beta)/(9 n))/(
                 1 + (2 beta)/(9 n)) + (2 beta)/(9 n)))/n] n)) (-((
              1 - (4 beta)/(9 n))/(1 + (2 beta)/(9 n))) + x/n))/(
          1 + (8 beta)/(9 n)))]]]], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];



UpperBoundHypergeometricv3[Nx_, n_, x_, p_] := 
 Module[{low, high, mid, var},
  
  
  (*The objective is to find the smallest value k such  that CDF[
  HypergeometricDistribution[n,k,Nx],x]<=p*)
  
  
  (*Lowest possible value*)
  low = Ceiling[Nx x/n];
  
  
  
  (*Highest possible value; 
  Uses results from probability thoery known as concentration \
inequalities*)
  high = 
   Floor[Nx Min[ 
      1, (upper[1, Log[1/p], x, n]/n), (x/n + 
        Sqrt[(Nx - n + 1) Log[1/p]/(2 Nx n)])]];
  
  
  
  (*Its not necessary to calculate the entire CDF; the contribution to \
the sum dimnishes rapidly. Hence instead of starting from x=
  0 we start from a value closer to x. 
  This if the first function in the If statement. 
  However the function has weird behaviour for small x;
  in which case we calculate CDF exactly*)
  cumulativeProb[k_] := 
   cumulativeProb[k] = 
    Piecewise[{{NProbability[(1 - 10^(-Max[0, Log[10, x] - 3])) x <= 
         var <= x, 
        var \[Distributed] HypergeometricDistribution[n, k, Nx]], 
       x >= 1000}, {CDF[HypergeometricDistribution[n, k, Nx], x], 
       x < 1000}}];
  
  
  (* the log of cdf and  and the population parameter is more or less \
a straightline;so we can kind of do an interpolation search*)
  iter[mid_] := 
   iter[mid] = 
    Ceiling[mid + (high - 
         mid) (Log[p] - 
          Log[cumulativeProb[mid]])/(Log[cumulativeProb[high]] - 
          Log[cumulativeProb[mid]])];
  
  
  (*Interpolation Search*)
  While[cumulativeProb[low] > p,
   low = iter[low];
   ];
  
  
  (*out*)
  low]

UpperBoundHypergeometric[10^4, 10^3, 3 10^1, 10^-20] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{1.58625, 1051}*)


UpperBoundHypergeometricv3[10^4, 10^3, 3 10^1, 10^-20]//AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.014737, 1051}*)


The biggest bottleneck is in evaluating the CDF. How do I speed up that part?
I'm also a bit concerned if the memoization is being used correctly. cumulativeProb is a very costly function and I dont want to have redundant calculations. How do I make it fool proof?
Also, should I expect any speed up from modifying the While loop. It does not look very Mathematica like and I wonder if this have  any effect.

Besides not using a function symbol as N as a local variable: FullSimplify the CDF is showing  a logical Case construct, that is time consuming. You can speed up by  memorizing results
cumulativeProb[k_] :=  cumulativeProb[k]  =  CDF[HypergeometricDistribution[n, k, Nn], x
by a factor 3..

Good point about the N. But I'm confused about the second part. I get that memorizing will speed up the subsequent evaluations but the loop itslef doesnt repeat over the same variable twice, so how can it help?

Just by implementing and comparison. If the function is called once only  it does not need a set delayed definition.

Thanks for the input!!
